# How to see shell script execution using Cronjob

Tags: shell, hadoop, cron, bigdata

I am currently running a cron job to schedule my shell script after a particular interval but i am not able to see my shell script execution and the log how can i see it.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the redirection sign (`>`) in order to redirect the `stdout` and/or `stderr` to a log file.

For example:

`0 0 * * * /path/to/shell-script.sh > /tmp/shell-script.log 2>&1`

Where:

- `0 0 * * *` means the script will run every day at midnight
- `/path/to/shell-script.sh`  - the path of the script
- `>` means redirect the stream to a file followed by the redirection sign
- `2>&1` means

  - File descriptor `1` is the standard output (`stdout`).
  - File descriptor `2` is the standard error (`stderr`).

Here is one way to remember this construct (although it is not entirely accurate): at first, `2>1` may look like a good way to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`. However, it will actually be interpreted as "redirect `stderr` to a file named `1`". `&` indicates that what follows is a file descriptor and not a filename. So the construct becomes: `2>&1`.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Can i generate different log files, when cron job runs after an interval of time ?

Comment: You can use `logrotate`. Read [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+TheGeekStuff+(The+Geek+Stuff))